# Extract a variable from within a load() function in jQuery for universal usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I have a slideshow module I'm working on, and I'd like to get the width/height of the original image (not the CSS rendered box model after loading) to calculate the width/height of the div necessary to contain it. The width/height  of the surrounding div is set to expand/contract accordingly with the size of the viewport.

Here's my HTML structure, which works fine to get everything:

```
<div id="listing_detail_photo_slider">

    <div id="listing_detail_photo_slider_strip"><div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/001.jpg&h=1440" alt="001 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/002.jpg&h=1440" alt="002 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/003.jpg&h=1440" alt="003 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/004.jpg&h=1440" alt="004 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/005.jpg&h=1440" alt="005 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/006.jpg&h=1440" alt="006 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/007.jpg&h=1440" alt="007 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/008.jpg&h=1440" alt="008 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/009.jpg&h=1440" alt="009 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/010.jpg&h=1440" alt="010 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/011.jpg&h=1440" alt="011 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/012.jpg&h=1440" alt="012 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/013.jpg&h=1440" alt="013 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/014.jpg&h=1440" alt="014 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/015.jpg&h=1440" alt="015 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/016.jpg&h=1440" alt="016 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/017.jpg&h=1440" alt="017 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/018.jpg&h=1440" alt="018 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/019.jpg&h=1440" alt="019 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/020.jpg&h=1440" alt="020 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/021.jpg&h=1440" alt="021 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/022.jpg&h=1440" alt="022 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/023.jpg&h=1440" alt="023 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/024.jpg&h=1440" alt="024 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/025.jpg&h=1440" alt="025 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/026.jpg&h=1440" alt="026 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/027.jpg&h=1440" alt="027 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/028.jpg&h=1440" alt="028 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/029.jpg&h=1440" alt="029 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/030.jpg&h=1440" alt="030 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/031.jpg&h=1440" alt="031 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/032.jpg&h=1440" alt="032 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/033.jpg&h=1440" alt="033 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/034.jpg&h=1440" alt="034 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/035.jpg&h=1440" alt="035 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            <div class="listing_gallery_thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/timthumb.php?src=http://www.djdenner.ca/homes/1/036.jpg&h=1440" alt="036 at 4112 Burkehill Road, Bayridge, West Vancouver" class="scale-with-grid" />
            </div>
            </div>
```

And here's my javascript code running on latest version of jQuery:

```
function showlisting_window_resize() {
// deduct the height of the top bar from the total height of the viewport to get slideshow width. 
// we want bottom to hit the bottom of screen on first view, until users scroll..

var slideshowh = window.windowh-$('#header_container').height();
$('#listing_detail_photo_slider').height(slideshowh);
$('#listing_detail_photo_slider_strip').height(slideshowh);



var slideshoww = 0; // start at 0, add up all the widths with gaps. 
$('#listing_detail_photo_slider_strip div').each(function(){
    slideshoww = slideshoww + $(this).width()+5;
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var pic_real = new Array();
    $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img[0]).attr("src")).load(
        function() {
            pic_real[0] = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
            pic_real[1] = this.height; // work for in memory images.

        }
    );

    console.log($(img[0]).attr("src")+' dimensions: '+pic_real[0]+' by '+pic_real[1]);

});

$('#listing_detail_photo_slider_strip').width(slideshoww).delay(500).css('top', '0px');

// now position the prev/next slides
// width:68px, height: 300px.
var prevnexttop = (slideshowh-300)/2; // middle align the prev/next buttons vertically.
$('#photo_slider_previous, #photo_slider_next').css('top',prevnexttop);

activate_carousel();
```

}

The console.log returns:

```
http://www.mydomain.ca/path/to/image.jpg dimensions: undefined by undefined
```

But when I put the console.log line WITHIN the function(){} portion under load(), it works.

In other words, how do I use the returned variables pic

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `console.log` works earlier then `image.load()` sets values for `pic_real`.

Add different `console.log` messages in `load` function and after it. You will see that the second message (after load) will be shown first.

Comment: OK I understand that. But still, how do I run a function based on the return outputs in pic_real var outside of the load() function?

Comment: It depends on what's your aim, I think.

Comment: As I'm rotating through each image, I want to set the width according to the target height (the height varies depending on the size of browser & screen on each load). Then adjust the width of the element based on the original ratio so there's no skewing. Because this has to be done on fly, and also re-size upon window size change, I cannot do it in CSS.